# PHP, check if user exists in database on table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to check if `var a=document.forms["reg"]["matricula"].value;` exists in my database, but this value the user will put on camp!

How can I check if var "a" exists in my database?

```
function validateForm()
{
var a=document.forms["reg"]["matricula"].value;
var b=document.forms["reg"]["nome"].value;
var c=document.forms["reg"]["cargo"].value;

if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b=="") && (c==null || c==""))
  {
  alert("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos!");
  return false;
  }

if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("A matrícula deve ser preenchida!");
  return false;
  }
if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("O nome deve ser preenchido!");
  return false;
  }
if (c==null || c=="")
  {
  alert("O cargo deve ser selecionado!");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: with a select query?

Comment: create a separate php file put your php code there then pull that page value via ajax from your js.

Comment: @Dagon, yea! A query

Comment: well um write one? what are you asking us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i check if var "a" exists in my database?

There are many ways to achieve it.

For your case, since you are tagging javascript.
After you have validate your form, send the form value to a separate query and return it to the same page. In this example, the query result will be return to an alert box.

```
function validateForm() {
//.......if(...) form validation starts....

    if (c==null || c=="") {
        alert("O cargo deve ser selecionado!");
        return false;
    }

//Submit matricula and or other value to query page and return result to an alert box example
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var querypage = "yourquerypagelocation.php";
    var form = document.getElementById("reg");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xhttp.responseText);//<- this will open a alert box with your query response
            }
        }
    xhttp.open("POST",querypage,true);
    xhttp.send(formData);
}
```

Because we are returning to an alert box only,be sure to keep your result as simple as possible, unless you are considering to return to the result to a div inside your page, which is not relevant to what you might be asking now.

**yourquerypage.php**

```
<?php
//whatever your other code might be (session, connection or whatsoever)
....
....
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
$query = ("SELECT matricula from [TABLE] where matricula LIKE '$matricula'")

if ($query){
    echo "Exists";//This will appear in alert box if query return true with the argument WHERE matricula LIKE $matricula.
    }else{
    echo "Not exists";
    }
?>
```

Hope this example helps.